# Dns: results of dig of domain.com with and without www

Tags: networking, dns, domain

I ran `dig` against a certain domain which I own, say for example domain.com.
After executing `dig domain.com`, I obtained results like the following:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
domain.com.     21600   IN  A   x.y.z.80
domain.com.     21600   IN  A   x.y.z.77
domain.com.     21600   IN  A   x.y.z.36
domain.com.     21600   IN  A   x.y.z.79
domain.com.     21600   IN  A   x.y.z.75
domain.com.     21600   IN  A   x.y.z.104
domain.com.     21600   IN  A   x.y.z.82
domain.com.     21600   IN  A   x.y.z.83
```

Executing `dig www.domain.com` gave instead

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.domain.com.     2715    IN  A   x.y.z.101
```

which is different from all the previous IPs. 
www.domain.com is a simple website and it has just a webserver, mailserver and DNS server.

But if the webserver x.y.z.101 is not included in the first list, what is the meaning of all those addresses? To what machines could they refer?

If I type `pop3.domain.com` a similar list is provided, with IP all different from the first list. My question is the same.

---

It looks strange that such a simple site has so multiple addresses, while for example `dig google.com` simpy provides

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     300 IN  A   216.58.212.110
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing unusual in these findings.  You can have multiple A records for a DNS entry, as in the first example.  You can have a single one as in the second and third examples.

You would generally have multiple IPs where you have a site hosted by multiple servers.  The results are all equal priority so people will resolve to a different server each time, distributing the load across the servers.

There is no requirement to have `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` (or `fdkfdkj.domain.com` or `dfjdf.sdfsdf.sdfdsf.domain.com`, `www` is not special, it is just convention) on the same server, they are entirely different DNS names.  It is common to have them on the same server though.  In the scenario above it is possible that the `www.domain.com` address redirects to `domain.com` and as that is all that happens on `www.domain.com` it does not need multiple servers to support the load.

There are other ways to distribute load.  One is to use a virtual IP, where the connections are made to a very fast load balancer that passes the request on to other servers.

Another way is to have tighter control over DNS and return a single IP address at a time, but different ones to each request, rather than multiple IPs, so that you can specify exactly which server you want to handle the connection, rather than having DNS just chuck out a bunch of IPs and let the load distribute randomly.